# How to define action to happen on triple key press?

Tags: evil, keystrokes

I'm using evil mode.

I'm looking for a convenient way to type German language Umlaut characters (`ä`, `ü`, `ö`, `Ä`, `Ü`, `Ö`, `ß`) while using an English US keyboard layout.  One idea that came to mind was to have triple key presses insert these characters, e.g., pressing `aaa` would insert `ä`, `OOO` would insert `Ö`, `SSS` would insert `ß`, and so on.

This should of course only happen while in `insert` state.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to accomplish this - any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question of how to have tripled keys insert certain characters, but have you tried using an input method? For example, `C-x RET C-\ german`.

An *input method* is a typical way to use a keyboard to insert characters for a different language.

> **`C-x RET C-\`** (translated from `C-x <return> C-\`) runs the command
>   `set-input-method` (found in `global-map`), which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `mule-cmds.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x RET C-\`, `menu-bar options mule set-input-method`.
>
> `(set-input-method INPUT-METHOD &optional INTERACTIVE)`
>
> Select and activate input method INPUT-METHOD for the current buffer.
>
> This also sets the default input method to the one you specify.
>   If `INPUT-METHOD` is `nil`, this function turns off the input method, and
>   also causes you to be prompted for a name of an input method the next
>   time you invoke `C-\`.
>   When called interactively, the optional arg `INTERACTIVE` is non-`nil`,
>   which marks the variable `default-input-method` as set for Custom buffers.
>
> To deactivate the input method interactively, use `C-\`.
>   To deactivate it programmatically, use `deactivate-input-method`.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the third keypress do what you want like this:

```
(defun insert-a-or-umlaut ()
  (interactive)
  (save-match-data
    (if (looking-back "aa")
        (progn
          (backward-delete-char 2)
          (insert "ä"))
      (self-insert-command 1))))

(global-set-key "a" 'insert-a-or-umlaut)
```

To get the others you can modify this pattern. In order to do this using evil and only in insert-mode you will have to bind the command in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like yasnippets:

```
(yas-define-snippets 'org-mode
             '(("aa" "ä")
               ("SS" "ß")))
```

Then you type aa and press tab, and it is converted to ä. Or you could make them more mnemonic, eg :a.

I tried this with abbrevs, but you have to type C-x ' after aaa to get it to expand before typing the next letter.

Comment: Thanks!  However, having to manually expand with `TAB` would be rather intrusive to fast typing.  I would very much prefer a solution which auto-expands without an additional keypress.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [key-chord](https://github.com/emacsmirror/emacswiki.org/blob/master/key-chord.el).  I'm not suggesting it's a good idea, but it can be done.

It doesn't seem like `key-chord` allows for triple-letter combinations, but you could use an uncommon character as a "prefix" and then adjust the delay timer.  If you still want to write both characters in sequence without replacement, type slower than the delay timer.

```
(require 'key-chord)
(key-chord-mode 1)
(evil-mode)

;; Define a key-chord only for evil insert mode.  When ";u" is typed,
;; call the unnamed function (i.e. the lambda) which in turn calls the
;; insert command for the given character.  The rest is just syntax
;; specifics.  Refer to An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp
;; for more information.
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map ";u" '(lambda() (interactive)(insert "ü")))
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map ";o" '(lambda() (interactive)(insert "ö")))

;; Max time delay between two key presses to be considered a key chord
(setq key-chord-two-keys-delay 0.3) ; default 0.1

;; Entering --INSERT-- mode
He liked glam bands like M;otley Cr;ue. ;; typing slowly
He liked glam bands like Mötley Crüe.   ;; typing quickly
```

Reference: [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not actually addressing "three keystrokes for inputting non-ascii characters", but "inputting non-ascii characters in few strokes".

Evil comes with [nvim's digraphs](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/digraph.txt).

In your case, in `INSERT`, you'd type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> and then:

- <kbd>a</kbd> and then <kbd>:</kbd> for ä
- <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> for ü
- <kbd>o</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> for ö
- <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> for Ä
- <kbd>U</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> for Ü
- <kbd>O</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> for Ö
- <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> for ß